# Change thickness of Audio Waveform drawn

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project in Unity 3D using a C# script that draws an Audio waveform onto a raw UI image. the script works fine, but in the draw waveform part of the script I'm having difficulty trying to increase the thickness of the line it draws. I'll include the code snippet here:

```
// draw the waveform 

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
    rawimage.SetPixel(
        (int)(width * i / size), 
        (int)(height * (samples [i] + 1f) / 2f), 
         waveformColor);
} // upload to the graphics card 

rawimage.Apply();
```

I tried changing some of the parameters but I don't think I fully understand how it's drawing the waveform.

Comment: The code snippet seems to draw a single pixel for each audio sample. Perhaps you want to connect them with lines. Note, for high fidelity you may want to use some approximation of sinc, rather than linear interpolation.

Comment: It seems to draw using two colors, a background color for the screen drawn onto the raw image and the waveform color, which is very thin, probably like you say about a pixel in thickness, I was looking at the values to see if I could somehow change the thickness of the line being drawn but was not having much luck